# RabbitMQ - Why I see only async.operations.all in queue list?

Tags: magento2, rabbit-mq, message-queue

I'm a little bit frustrated with Magento 2 queue for RabbitMQ.

I have setup RabbitMQ, my env.php has such lines

```
'queue' => [
    'consumers_wait_for_messages' => 1,
    'amqp' => [
        'host' => 'rabbitmq',
        'port' => '5672',
        'user' => 'magento',
        'password' => 'magento',
        'virtualhost' => '/'
    ]
],
'cron_consumers_runner' => [
    'cron_run' => true,
    'max_messages' => 20000,
    'consumers' => []
],
```

but I see only async.operations.all in rabbitmqctl list_queues:

```
/ # rabbitmqctl list_queues
Timeout: 60.0 seconds ...
Listing queues for vhost / ...
name    messages
async.operations.all
```

Looks like queue is working, but **why I don't see any other Magento 2 records in queue?** Like
product_action_attribute.update
product_action_attribute.website.update
Strange that I see new queue messages in queue_message table in Magento DB. I see that some of items have connection="db" in queue_topology.xml. Are they executed using RabbitMQ or using Magento own queue implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, all of Magento's default queues are defined with a `db` connection. The only one with a configured `amqp` connection is the 'async.operations.all' queue.

However, you can move the queues to `amqp` connection. Check the [Magento official documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/message-queues/message-queues.html#change-message-queue-from-mysql-to-amqp) on how to change this. The configurations mentioned there should be usable if added to your `app/etc/env.php`.

Good luck!

---

***LE*** I can confirm you can do this :) out of curiosity I just moved all my magento instance's queues to RabbitMQ. [Here](https://gist.github.com/dianabotean/82dc9b39fec5f39530d7f550b97ee526) is a gist with my configuration of the Open Source 2.4.1 queues moved to Rabbit. However, this is just the proof of concept about how can you do this and not a complete validation regarding performance for example.

Comment: Can you share how you moved all queues to Rabbit MQ, your env.php config and did you disable cron completely?

Comment: @paj hey there, i edited my answer above to include the part of the env.php which I edited in order to move the queues to rabbit. I didn't disable the crons in my installation.

Comment: that is very useful, thankyou. I gues at some point message q’s will be completely removed from the db (like search). I use docker containers as consumers so will be interesting to try and disable cron completely and use a consumer container to process all messaging...

Comment: i hope you are right, @paj and that queues will be moved to the message broker. would be great! and yes, i also use docker envs and totally makes sense, no need to have supervisor or other monitoring tool to keep the consumer cron up all time. i agree.

Comment: what i meant here was that it would be nice to 1. have all queues to rabbit, 2. would be also good to have the consumers externalized (by default, the queues are processed in magento), but it would be nice to have them outside magento as well ;)

Comment: thanks for your comments, I have been looking into exactly how the ConsumersRunner cron works today and it's all a lot clearer now, I recommend looking at Magento\MessageQueue\Model\Cron\ConsumersRunner::run() :)

Comment: Glad to hear this! I am sure the mechanism will evolve in future versions and it will more helpful in the future :)