# Does the default Magento 2.4.2 Require RabbitMQ Asynchronous message queueing?

Tags: magento2.4, rabbit-mq, message-queue, async

Does Magento 2.4.2 (2.4.x) open source REQUIRE asynchronous message queueing (and thus installation of RabbitMQ) by default?

I was under the impression that 'asynchronous message queueing' is an option and not a requirement.

But after installation I see a common error out there with ["async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured"].  With this error log message it seems the default installation requires amqp (Async message queue protocol) connection configuration and thus RabbitMQ -- as a default setup -- which means Asynchronous message queueing is REQUIRED for Magento 2.4 to work in a base/default setup.

Is this correct?  AMQP and RabbitMQ are REQUIRED (not an option)?

I see lots of confusion on the net about this .. including this thread:
[Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269928/consumer-async-operations-all-skipped-as-required-connection-amqp-is-not-con)

But in the above thread there doesn't seem to be a consensus.  It seems to me so far that RabbitMQ  is required by default for Magento 2.4 to work properly. Can anyone confirm?

Thanks In Advance

Ray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error appears indeed if you don't have an amqp connection configured to point to rabbit message broker. And will appear indefinitely (if you don't set up the connection) as this is triggered by a Magento cron which processes the bulk update operations (please refer to https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/message-queues/bulk-operations.html for further details).

If you don't use bulk operations at all, you can omit installing rabbitmq, but you will see that error log message forever. But if instead you are using bulk operations in your project, then you MUST install rabbitmq, otherwise, these operations won't be processed at all.

---

***LE:***
The official documentation says you have to add the `queue` section in the `app/etc/env.php` file, but if it exists, you just have to add under it the `amqp` key and configure it. It will look something like this:

```php
[
(...)
    'queue' => [
        (...)
        'amqp' => [
            'host' => '<rabbitmq_host>',
            'port' => '<rabbitmq_port>',
            'user' => '<rabbitmq_user>',
            'password' => '<rabbitmq_pass>',
            'virtualhost' => '/',
            'ssl' => true
        ],
   ]
]
```

Now, if you check the registered consumers from a vanilla Magento installation, you will see that only the `async.operations.all` one is set to have an AMQP connection:

```xml
<consumer name="async.operations.all" queue="async.operations.all" connection="amqp"
             consumerInstance="Magento\AsynchronousOperations\Model\MassConsumer"/>
```

all other default consumers will be processed by from the db registered queues and will have no interference whatsoever with rabbitmq. they will continue to work as they did before you configured your amqp connection - only the bulk operations will be processed via the queue registered in rabbitmq.

Comment: Thanx.  So, default installation of open-source RabbitMQ is needed for Bulk Operations - OK.  Based on this, some operations (BULK) will use 'ampq / RabbitMQ' for Asynchronous communication while the rest continue to be Synchronous via MySQL?

... Doc says to "ADD" a 'queue' section to app/etc/env.php -- BUT a queue section already exists:  'queue' => [ 'consumers_wait_for_messages' => 1 ],
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/install-rabbitmq.html

... So CHANGEING that to 'amqp' method will force ALL comm to be Async?  Thus needing further configuration now?

Comment: please check the update in my answer :) hopefully, it will make more sense now what you have to do and how this works. cheers and good luck!

Comment: Just to confirm:  My queue is: 
'queue' => ['consumers_wait_for_messages' => 1], 

APPENDED:

'queue' => [
        'consumers_wait_for_messages' => 1,
      'amqp' => [ ...

Comment: yeah, looks good

Comment: Yes perfect.  That worked!  This is a complete answer to the question.  By default, the Magento opensource needs ampq setup for 'async.operations.all'.  The connection needs to be appended to the 'queue' section in app/etc/env.php as described by Diana above.

Comment: Diana, by default Mage runs consumers_runner.  But docs say that we need to start message queue. But the default cron is already running: Consumer "async.operations.all".  Do we have to run:  `bin/magento queue:consumers:start <consumer_name>`  ?

I also get an error in the CRON.log:

`main.CRITICAL: NOT_FOUND - no queue 'async.operations.all' in vhost 'host' {"exception":"[object] (PhpAmqpLib\\Exception\\AMQPProtocolChannelException(code: 404): NOT_FOUND - no queue 'async.operations.all' in vhost 'host' at ...`  But in my RabbitMQ admin I see:  Queue async.operations.all in virtual host.

Comment: it's an 'either or' situation. running the crons with the default setup should work properly and you shouldn't need to run `queue:consumers:start` as they are managed by the crons. however, if you change your settings and disable the consumers runner by configuration in env.php, then you need to run the command to start the consumers (check this thread for details https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/324970/rabbitmq-and-cron-consumers-runner/331045#331045). as for your error, run `setup:upgrade` to force the creation of the queue in rabbitmq. good luck!

Comment: I had to create that in the Rabbit MQ admin panel.  Thank you.  All good now.

Answer (score 1):

Complete answer per Diana's help:

1. Default Magento open source requires `amqp` (RabbitMQ) for `async.operations.all`.
2. If you installed Magento before installing your 'amqp' (RabbitMQ) you need to append the 'queue' section in app/etc/env.php with your 'amqp' credentials as follows:

   ```
   'queue' => [
   'consumers_wait_for_messages' => 1,
   'amqp' => [
       'host' => 'your-amqp-host',
       'port' => '5672',
       'user' => 'your-user-name',
       'password' => 'your-password',
       'virtualhost' => 'your-virutal-host-directory',
       'ssl' => 'true'
   ]],
   ```